# Matching polygons to intersecting polygons using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-join, overlapping-features, multi-polygon

I am trying to match a set of polygons (A) to another set of polygons (B) using ArcMap. Both sets overlap themselves, and each other. Here's an example of what it looks like in my data:

[image: Text]

The green polygons are the (A) set (about 12000 polygons), while the blue polygons are the (B) set (about 30000 polygons). Ultimately, the dataset that I want to create should have, for every polygon in (A), the set of polygons in (B) that it overlaps, with the data from (B)'s attributes table and the area of the overlap.

I've tried using the intersect tool, but it has crashed on me twice now after several hours.

Is there a better way to do this?

I haven't used ArcGIS Pro before, but have access to it and would be happy to use some tool from there.

Comment: I regularly Intersect tens of millions or polygons with tens of thousands, and it runs for under 30 minutes. You need to make sure your polygon feature classes are valid (Check Geometry) and/or just run Repair Geometry (won't hurt valid layers) on both layers.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with ArcGIS is that if you use features with arc elements (ellipses in your case) of large dataset, it tends to fail. My workaround is to try Generalize-d copy of my data in overlay analysis. Basically create a copy of your circular data and use Generalize tool from Editing toolset. If it does not help, you may also tweak the resolution of your data which may simplify your data further. In both cases you will be using a modified version of the data, not the original which might be of concern. This is a trade-off between loss of accuracy vs. processing capabilities of the software.